# Setting up permissions for non-registered users

Tags: users

How do I set permissions for non-register users?

**Step 1**: I registered Drupal 7 in my system.

**Step 2**: I wrote a module for `user_register()`.

**Step 3**: When I call the menu callback an access denied error  is shown.

How should i set permission to non-register users to register?

Comment: May you report the code you use to call the menu callback? Which menu callback are you calling?

Comment: why do you need user_register() if you're dealing with unregistered users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your menu item definitions, you can specify TRUE as the access callback to make the item always accessible.

```
<?php
  function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['abc/def'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
      'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
    return $items;
  }

?>
```

See http://api.drupal.org/api/function/_menu_check_access/7

Hope this helps,
Mark